# Can't get my simple react timer to work without causing endless loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

I'm trying to create a simple timer in my react app that counts up from 0 to 10 and then stops. But I can't get it to work without getting caught in an infinite loop.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Countdown = () => {
  const [countdown, setCountdown] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCountdown(countdown + 1);
    }, 1000);
    if (countdown >= 10) {
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, [countdown]);

  return <div>{countdown}</div>;
};

export default Countdown;
```

Comment: Because you are only clearing the interval when `countdown` is over ten and the useEffect runs every time `countdown` changes, you are setting a *new* interval on every render, so by the time you do clear (one) of the intervals there are still multiple intervals running, each triggering more to be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to stop using `setInterval` if it is greater than `10`. But you are clearing the interval if it is greater than `10` but the `setCountdown` still setting `countdown`.

But you should use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` and initialize the `countdown` to `1`

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-microservice-orzwq?file=/src/Countdown.js:0-415)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Countdown = () => {
  const [countdown, setCountdown] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timeout;
    if (countdown < 10) {
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        setCountdown(countdown + 1);
      }, 1000);
    }

    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [countdown]);

  return <div>{countdown}</div>;
};

export default Countdown;
```

Comment: Why an interval instead of a timeout?

Comment: @Nick About to add more info, But you commented

Comment: Why did you remove the cleanup function from the effect?

Comment: this works as expected, but I still have a few questions.
1) Whats the purpose of starting the state at 1 instead of 0?
2) what's the purpose of returning the clearTimeout as a function? can't you just put a return statement at the end, and the timeout will finish up when the second passes?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// here is the alternative to count the process time.
console.time('looper');
for(let a=0; a<100000; a++){}
console.timeEnd('looper');
```